# symbol lookup error when using my Qt plugin from inside of shared library

Tags: c++, linux, qt

This is under Linux, 64 bit, GCC 4.8.2.

I have an application which is made of:

- A shared library (below called CORE), a core of the application, it implements most of the logic and it also handles loading my custom plugins.
- An executable (below called EXEC) which is linked to the core CORE. It starts the `QApplication` and uses classes from CORE, but also adds some more classes on its own.
- Custom plugins, based on Qt's plugin framework (that is they implement pure virtual interface class, they inherit `QObject`, etc). All plugins are loaded with `QPluginLoaded` and they are working. **Plugins loading is performed by the class from CORE.**

It can be represented more or less like this:

```
EXEC               <- this I run
 `- CORE.so        <- this is dynamically linked with EXEC
     +- plugin1.so <- those are loaded dynamically by QPluginLoader
     +- plugin2.so
     (...)
     `- pluginN.so
```

The problem:

It looks like **plugins cannot use any symbols from EXEC**, even they are loaded by CORE, which is loaded by EXEC. Is that really a case? I thought that the application that is running provides all its symbols to any loaded libraries in runtime.

It compiles fine, but in runtime, when the plugin uses any symbol from EXEC, application crashes with message: *symbol lookup error*.

There is no problem with using CORE symbols, only EXEC symbols are not available to plugins.

I'm sure that the symbol implementation is compiled in - I have made several test with a very simple cases to avoid any complexity. I have also checked symbol in midnight commander (F3 key) and it is there, in the EXEC.

EDIT: I have just tested the case when `QPluginLoader` is created and `load()` on it is called directly from the `main()` function from the EXEC binary and it still doesn't work. It's like symbols from CORE were somehow "exported" and symbols from EXEC were not... but this is Linux, there's no symbols exporting, right?

Comment: So it appears that under Linux symbols are also exported or not. Symbols for shared libraries are exported by default and symbols in the executable are not - that explains my problem. I will try `-rdynamic` later today and if it works, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Final_Contest: Yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected in my own comment to my question, the `-rdynamic` passed to linker for EXEC solved the problem.

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thanks!